# SSRS in SharePoint integrated mode - ORA-03135 when querying Oracle database

Tags: oracle, sharepoint, reporting-services

We have successfully installed SSRS in SharePoint integrated mode. We can run reports with data sources pointing to MS SQL database.
We need to add support for reports querying Oracle 12c database.

After the drivers installation we can create a data source with "Oracle Database" data source type. But when we try the "Test Connection" button, we always get the **"ORA-03135: connection lost" error**. Reports based on this data source always fail.

We use these versions: SharePoint 2016, MSSQL 2016, Oracle 12c.

Did anybody come across this error? How did you solve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had to install an Oracle patch to ODAC drivers. After installation of the patch we got rid from this error.

Most likely the error was raising because of the Oracle Advanced Security option.